# executing parallel task in a java method

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm quite new to parallel programming in java. I wrote two methods that each operate on a set of data in parallel. Method A has to complete before Method B starts. I would like to know when the method executing parallel Tasks terminates. Is it:

- when all tasks finish execution? or
- After all tasks are submitted for execution.

**NB:** I have monitored the Threads with java visualVM and i realized the threads spends most of the time in the state monitor and waiting.

Comment: If method A has to complete before method B can start, then they are not operating in parallel and there is no point in making the methods run in separate threads...

Comment: @Jesper method A executes an operation(lets say C) on a set of data in parallel and method B does the same on that set of data. But B should only start when A completes because it  applies his operation( say D) in parallel on the resulting data from A.

Comment: The best way to insure that B() will only start after A() completes is to have _one thread_ call A() first, and then call B().

Comment: What do you mean when you say "two methods that both operate on a set of data in parallel?"  You have explicitly said that you do not want the two method calls to overlap, so if they are not called in parallel with each other, then what _is_ happening "in parallel?"

Comment: I mean that A() processes the set of data in parallel,  then B() does the same, both applying different operations on the data set.

Comment: @Gilbert so B depends on the results of A?

Comment: Yes B()  depends on the result of A().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged this with `executorservice`, so I assume you're using a Java `ExecutorService`.  The answer depends on exactly what your methods do.

If your methods merely call `ExecutorService.submit()` or `ExecutorService.execute()` on each of their respective parallel tasks, they exit as soon as all tasks are submitted; the parallel tasks may still be executing when the method exits.

If you wish to wait for completion of all the tasks associated with a method, first call `ExecutorService.submit()` for each task, storing the returned `Futures`.  Then, once all tasks have been submitted, call `Future.get()` on each of the `Futures`.  `Future.get()` does not return until the associated task completes, so once all the calls to `Future.get()` have returned, all the tasks have completed and you can exit the method and go on to the next method.

Comment: The second part describe what I'm currently doing. Thanks for the clarification.